# When are the Clojure core.async go-blocks useful?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

Since the thread pool running go-blocks is fairly small, it seems that some operations inside go-blocks aren't recommended. For example doing [blocking I/O is bad](http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2013/07/07/coreasync-and-blocking-io), and doing compute-heavy operations is bad. A few such operations running in go-blocks will hog the entire thread pool, and no other go-blocks would be able to run at all.

What most common scenarios do Clojure programmers use go-blocks for? Is it mainly useful for working with already asynchronous libraries? Transform callback-using libraries/code into a more palatable channel variant? I'll be very interested to see practical examples where go-blocks with parking channel ops are preferable to threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, use `go` blocks when you are using `core.async` channels in an asynchronous clojure application.

`core.aysnc` gives you built-in backpressure, that is, a mechanism which says "no, I will not create new workers because we're busy already" (i.e., creating 100000 `go` blocks will not wreck your system, but don't try this at home with threads, or a thread pool with an unbounded queue). This is a big win, and eliminates the need to synchronize the threads to do this yourself. Problems which require backpressure (such as producer-consumer problems) often fit this model well, and core.async is a great choice.

However, the `go` macro is not part of the clojure core library, and it is not intended to be used as a general purpose tool to achieve concurrency. Its purpose is to provide an abstraction on top of asynchronous code to make it flow in a more synchronous way. Consider your use case and if the model fits, go for it!

Answer (score 5):

Each thread requires a minimum amount of memory ([default 1MB on 64-bit linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom)) for its stack, etc. While several hundred threads may not be a problem on an average computer, several thousand or more may consume a lot of memory (i.e. 1000 threads => 1GB memory). And, these resources are consumed even when the thread is blocked (not running).

Suppose you have a task that is only running 1-10% of the time. Then using regular threads consumes 10x-100x more resources than required. Since go blocks share threads via "parking", you can reduce the thread resources required by 10x-100x.  This is the benefit.

A second benefit is that `core.async` can be used in ClojureScript and run in the browser.  Since JavaScript (which CLJS compiles into) has only a single thread, `core.async` allows one to have the illusion of multithreading in the browser even though regular Java threads are not available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I have a task running 1% of the the time, I could save ~100 MB of memory? Presumably to save larger amounts of memory (in the GBs+) I'd need to have tasks running 0.1% of the time? I guess my question was, for (the JVM) Clojure - what kinds of tasks are these?

Comment: That's up to you! One example would be any kind of I/O that would block a thread, either to the network or a disk/DB.

Comment: But blocking I/O with go blocks is bad, isn't it? It blocks the whole thread, so a small number of these block the whole thread pool?